# My controller won't recieve the input from the user (Spring boot)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My controller won't work - like adding the data into my DB.

```java
public class BukuController {

    @Autowired
    private BukuService bukuservice;

    @PostMapping(value = "/createBuku", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createBook(@RequestParam("judul") String judul, @RequestParam("tahun") int tahun, @RequestParam("penulis") String penulis) {
        System.out.println("Judul   : " + judul);
        System.out.println("Tahun   : " + tahun);
        System.out.println("Penulis : " + penulis);
        try {
            bukuservice.getCreate(judul, penulis, tahun);
            System.out.println("Berhasil");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Gagal");
        }
        //
        return "detail";
    }
}
```

detail.html (Edited 3:48 PM because someone comment need file html i use for insert the data)

```
<body>
<form action="/buku/createBuku" method="post">Form Detail Buku<br><br>
    Judul Buku&nbsp;: <input type="text" name="judul"><br>
    Tahun&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" name="tahun"><br>
    Nama Penulis&nbsp;: <input type="text" name="penulis"><br>
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

I am new using thymeleaf. Can you give give some advice? Maybe I'm using the wrong dependencies or I am wrong on other java files like the model or service.

It's failing to save the input to the table and no warnings or errors pop up, it's running smoothly.

Comment: Post the code in   `bukuservice.getCreate(judul, penulis, tahun);` and is the data comes in the backend . Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: If your `System.out.println` log somethings this is not a thymeleaf issue but maybe a repository problem

Comment: System.out.println -> just want to try check the user's input we got that or not
but when i try input in detail.html. its sending log in my console like this :

2019-07-23 13:58:05.558  INFO 6796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-23 13:58:05.558  INFO 6796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-23 13:58:05.570  INFO 6796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms

Comment: this error reveal when i adding thymeleaf ( because i want change into use thymeleaf). so i don't know why my code won't work like before i add thymeleaf

Comment: add html code on your question

Comment: Done add my html that i use it.

Comment: annotate class level with @RequestMapping('/buku')